# Pure Javascript or Prototype-based free timeline libraries

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I've been struggling for a while finding a free JavaScript timeline visualization. I am using Prototype (not jQuery, thus excluding SIMILE Widget) and I do not care too much about older browsers.

Ideally, the timeline would also be usable on mobile phones.

Do you have any idea if any of the existing libraries out there meet these requirements?

Comment: Just a note, you can [use jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) in conjunction with other libraries/frameworks.

Comment: There's also the Scriptaculous libarary [Tinderbox Timeline](http://www.eastgate.com/Tinderbox/Tutorials/TheTinderboxTimelineLibr.html).

Comment: Hi, indeed, I can use jQuery as well, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Thanks for the link to Tinderbox, I already checked this lib but it is not free.

Comment: I ended up importing jQuery just to be able SIMILE widget... the latter is quite nice tho.

Comment: Tinderbox does look nice, not surprised it's for-pay. If you're ever looking for any visualization libraries, checkout [InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/).

Comment: why import a library just for one component because you can, that's bad practice, and bloats an app for no real gain. There are plenty of pure javascript components that are far lighter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try GreenSock animation framework: http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/

Even though it's not strictly prototype.js, it can work flawlessly together - using prototype.js as utility framework and GreenSock as animation framework for it (instead of script.aculo.us).

This way you can get both prototype's awesome extensions and GreenSock's incredible performance + timelines.